# Using check age middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just learning laravel and now i'm stuck at Middleware stuff. I have class AdultMiddleware.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdultMiddleware
{

  /**
  * Handle an incoming request.
  *
  * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
  * @param \Closure $next
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if (Session::get('age') < 18) {
      return view('search');
    }

    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and it's short name in Kernel.php :

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'adult' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdultMiddleware::class,
];
```

And in web.php :

```
Route::get('middle', array('as' => 'middle', 'age' => '16', 'before' => 'adult', function()
{
    return view('welcome');
}));
```

As you see in routes I set age as 16 , but still it returns welcome instead of search. What I'm doing wrong? I know it may sound newbie, but I did try to google and had no luck. That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning middleware to a route:

```
Route::get(..., ['middleware' => 'adult', ...]);

Route::get(..., ...)->middleware('adult');
```

`before` is for filters which don't exist any more in Laravel since middleware replaced filters.

```
Route::get('middle', ['as' => 'middle', 'middleware' => 'adult', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}]);
```

[Laravel Docs - 5.2 - Middleware - Assigning Middleware to routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

[Laravel Docs - 5.5 - Middleware - Assigning Middleware to routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

If your middleware is going to check a session variable, you could add a route to be able to set that session variable as you like.

```
Route::get('set/age/{age}', function ($age) {
    session(['age' => $age]);

    return redirect()->route('middle');
});
```

That will set the `age` variable in the session and redirect you to your 'middle' route.

Also you may want to return a redirect to the search page instead of returning a view from the middleware.

Comment: Yes this one worked, but now I get error like: `Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Session' not found` , with age I want to set the variable age, so I could test if the middleware working. It's only for testing purpose

Comment: Import Session above your class name. `use Session;`